# [Dagger/MissingBinding].Kotlinjvm.functions.Function1<? super java.lang.Integer.Unit> cannot be provided

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Cannot provide `kolin lambda` of type `(Int) -> Unit`. However `() -> Unit` can be provided :- eg:-

```
@Module
class LambdaModule {
   @Provides
   fun getIntArgLambda(): (Int) -> Unit = {}

   @Provides
   fun getNoArgLambda(): () -> Unit = {}

   @Provides
   fun getRecyclerViewAdater(intLambda: (Int) -> Unit, noArg: () -> Unit): CustomAdapter = CustomAdapter(intLambda, noArg)
}
```

**Error** :-

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super java.lang.Integer,kotlin.Unit> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

However, if i don't use `getIntArgLambda()`, its working :-

```
 @Provides
 fun getRecyclerViewAdater(noArg: () -> Unit): CustomAdapter = CustomAdapter({}, noArg)
```

The above code is working :-

> Why can't i provide `(Int) -> Unit` param to any method within the same `module`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a variance problem. It's related to the Java wildcards.

The function:

```
@Provides
fun getIntArgLambda(): (Int) -> Unit = {}
```

In Java returns:

```java
kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<java.lang.Integer, kotlin.Unit>
```

While the parameter `intLambda` of the function:

```
@Provides
fun getRecyclerViewAdater(intLambda: (Int) -> Unit, noArg: () -> Unit): CustomAdapter = CustomAdapter(intLambda, noArg)
```

In Java is:

```java
kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super java.lang.Integer, kotlin.Unit>
```

To suppress the wildcard you can use `@JvmSuppressWildcards`:

```
@Module
class LambdaModule {
   @Provides
   fun getIntArgLambda(): (Int) -> Unit = {}

   @Provides
   fun getNoArgLambda(): () -> Unit = {}

   @Provides
   fun getRecyclerViewAdater(intLambda: Function1<@JvmSuppressWildcards Int, Unit>, noArg: () -> Unit): CustomAdapter = CustomAdapter(intLambda, noArg)
}
```